# Asynchronous web application with ASP.NET MVC 4 and Angularjs

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, angularjs

We are planning an update for a web application implemented using ASP.NET Web Form. We'd like to inctroduce MVC pattern, so we are basically oriented to MVC 4.

We are also evaluating AngularJs, that seems a great MVC framework for web development.

I've read a bit about using AngularJs + Web Api, but I have no experience about Single Page Applications or asynchronous applications. For example, how they implement authentication?

I'd like to know if there's a well known architecture for asynchronous application developing, and how can I implement this with MVC 4 + AngularJs.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS is a great MVW (Model-View-Whatever) framework and already provides a lot of "architecture" for developing a web app. Therefore, I am not sure why you would want to use MVC4 + AngularJS. AngularJS has asynchronous built in - **$http** and **$resource** can be used to make asnync calls.

They also recently added [animation support](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-angularjs.html) making web animations super easy to implement. So there is a lot that AngularJS has already built in and one just needs to become familiar with it.  I suggest you look at some sample applications such as [this one](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-angularjs.html).

Comment: I also need to implement authentication and role authorization in my app. Does Angular provide some utilities to deal with these?

Comment: Check out http://www.frederiknakstad.com/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/. You would create a module to handle your authentication.

Answer (score 5):

instead of using WebAPI, take a closer look at www.servicestack.net

AngularJS with servicestack backend -> works like a charm! i'll never switch back to webapi!

Comment: do you know if there an example / prototype for angularjs->Servicestack, TBH it's the first time I ever seen it and it looks awesome!

Comment: Service Stack + AngularJS Example: http://razor.servicestack.net/rockstars?View=AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of guides around for doing so. Since WebApi is a RESTful service you can use angularjs [`$http`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) or/and [`$resource`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) for consuming it.

Additionally there are libraries out there for consuming RESTful services which work as a middle man for frameworks like Angular and MVC.  Check out [This Visual Studio template.](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/BreezeAngularSpaTemplateVsix)